# How can I index the right node on a XML file?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xml-parsing

So I was trying to read the nodes and write their fields on an Excel workbook, however I'm having troubles to index a specific field that I want. The XML structure is like:

```
<root>
  <data name="Admin" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Administrador</value>
  </data>
 </root>
```

Now the problem is that I had no problem to get the text inside the node  but I also wanted to get the text inside the "" right after data name. The VB code is as it follows:

```
Dim XDoc As Object
Dim myNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList, myChildNodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim myElement As IXMLDOMElement
Dim myNode As IXMLDOMNode, myChildNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim nNode As Integer
Dim nChildNode As Integer

Set XDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
XDoc.async = False: XDoc.validateOnParse = False
XDoc.load (vFileName)
Set myNodes = XDoc.SelectNodes("//data/value")
If myNodes.Length > 0 Then
    For nNode = 0 To myNodes.Length - 1
       Set myNode = myNodes(nNode)
       Set myChildNodes = myNode.ChildNodes ' Get the children of the first node.
       For nChildNode = 0 To myChildNodes.Length - 1
          vNode = myChildNodes(nChildNode).Text
          vRange2 = "A" + Trim(Str(vLineTAG))
          Range(vRange2).Value = vNode
       Next nChildNode
    Next nNode
Else
'Stuff and all
End If
```

So here I'm referencing "value" and vNode is getting the Administrador string inside the node above, but when I reference only data, it returns an empty string, the range which receives it is blanc, and the next child node returns what is inside the value node as expected. Don't know what am I missing here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work

```
Dim ElementAttribute As IXMLDOMAttribute

Set ElementAttribute = myNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("name")
Debug.Print ElementAttribute.Text
```